# Shell - How to deal with find -regex?

Tags: regex, shell, find

I need to look in a directory for sub-directories that all start by "course" but they have version next. For example

```
course1.1.0.0
course1.2.0.0
course1.3.0.0
```

So how should I modify my command to make it give me the right list of directories?

```
find test -regex "[course*]" -type d
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do:

```
find test -type d -regex '.*/course[0-9.]*'
```

it will match files whose name is `course` plus an amount of numbers and dots.

For example:

```
$ ls course*
course1.23.0  course1.33.534.1  course1.a  course1.a.2
$ find test -type d -regex '.*course[0-9.]*'
test/course1.33.534.1
test/course1.23.0
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the brackets, and use the proper wildcard syntax for regexes (`.*`):

```
find test -regex "course.*" -type d
```

You can also use the more familiar shell wildcard syntax, by using the `-name` option instead of `-regex`:

```
find test -name 'course*' -type d
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a regex for precise matching of version number sub directories:

```
find . -type d -iregex '^\./course\([0-9]\.\)*[0-9]$'
```

**TESTING:**

```
ls -d course*
course1.1.0.0   course1.1.0.5   course1.2.0.0   course1.txt

find . -type d -iregex '^\./course\([0-9]\.\)*[0-9]$'
./course1.1.0.0
./course1.1.0.5
./course1.2.0.0
```

**UPDATE:** To match `[0-9].` exactly 3 times use this find command:

```
find test -type d -regex '.*/course[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]$'
```

Comment: Well, this is a more specific and sofisticated answer, but I don't understand why It doesn't work when I am not in the directory where I'm looking for the sub-directories. I am obliged to go through "cd test" then to do "find . " instead of "find test " directly... But it is a nice suggestion. +1

Comment: @Farah: Not sure why it didn't work for you. I have showed my output also above. You could use: `find test -type d -iregex '^\./course\([0-9]\.\)*[0-9]$'` also

Comment: That didn't work for me either, however when I do the following it works : `find test -type d -regex '.*/course\([0-9]\.\)*[0-9]$'`

Comment: Is there a way to oblige having [0-9]\.\ exactly 3 times instead of * ?

Comment: Yeah, that gives the desired result, +1. By the way, I guess I know why the solution you suggested `find . -type d -iregex '^\./course\([0-9]\.\)*[0-9]$'` doesn't work when I'm not in the parent directory, which is "test". It is because `find`command gives the path too  : `test/course5.4.0.0`, however, you are using the `^` symbol which impose a certain pattern in the begining. Here it is the right one : `find test -type d -iregex '^test/course\([0-9]\.\)*[0-9]$'`

Comment: @Farah; yes you got it. That i exactly the reason it didn't work for you.

Comment: `find` is different than `ls` which doesn't give the entire path. Here it is a command that gives the same solution and using ls+egrep : `ls test | egrep  '^course([0-9].)+[0-9]+[a-zA-Z_0-9]*'` . But, files respecting the pattern would be displayed too..

Comment: `find` is more suitable because it is recursive, finding only directories and can do it all in single command.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. And I had to switch to a solution by `ls` due to SVN which offers `svn ls` and not `svn find`...

Comment: Ah I see, yes I have also used `svn ls` similarly.